# Flask SQLAlchemy Adjacency List Relationships¶

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up a table that should include a foreign key that points to the table itself just like a tree with nodes and therefore a parent and children.

I followed the example on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/self_referential.html which looks like the following

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node")
```

When implementing this class in Flask I get the following error:

The foreign key associated with column 'node.parent_id' could not find table 'node' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is the relationship("something") looks for the class with **tablename** = "something" (not the class name).
See if changing it to
children = relationship("node") works

Comment: This is not true.  The first argument to [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.argument) is "A mapped class, or actual Mapper instance, representing the target of the relationship"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33481169)